# Championship points decided by a net cord?

Tags: trivia, tennis

In 1988, Boris Becker dramatically beat Ivan Lendl in 5 sets in the [Masters tournament at Madison Square Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Nabisco_Masters_%E2%80%93_Singles). The final set went to tie breaks, ending with a backhand net cord by Becker.

Have there been other major tournaments where the championship point was decided by a net cord shot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there have been a few instances of the net cord deciding championship point in both the Men's and Women's tours:

**ATP**

> [Final - CA-TennisTrophy (Vienna) 2002, Roger Federer vs. Jiří Novák](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHQm-6FqkXI) - The 21 year old Federer claimed his 8th title by striking a forehand which clipped the tape and fell on the side Novák.
>
> 6–4, 6–1, 3–6, 6–4
>
> [Final - Miami 2006, Roger Federer vs. Ivan Ljubicic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJ-7qbmF42Y) - To cap off a thrilling final that went into a tiebreak all three sets, Roger ended it with a lucky net cord on the return.
>
> 7-6<sup>(5)</sup>, 7-6<sup>(4)</sup>, 7-6<sup>(6)</sup>.
>
> [Final - Gerry Weber Open 2010, Lleyton Hewitt vs. Roger Federer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5n7cNw_xf0k) - The three set final victory ended in a mid-rally net cord that fell the way of Hewitt at the gasp of the crowd. This victory broke a 15-match losing streak against Federer for Hewitt, and was the first time Federer had lost since 2002 in Halle.
>
> 3–6, 7–6<sup>(4)</sup>, 6–4.
>
> [Final - Gazprom Hungarian Open 2018, Marco Cecchinato vs. John Millman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQiIc6JRZ1Q) - The net cord shot was struck by the eventual champion and 1st time ATP Tour tournament winner Marco Cecchinato.
>
> 7-5, 6-4.

---

**WTA**

> [Final - Wimbledon 1988, Steffi Graf vs. Martina Navratilova](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1k3a1c) - In what proved to be a hard fought match, Graf pulled it out against then 6-time defending champion on a net cord return. Graf's slam victory proved to be a crucial one as it was the penultimate slam that enabled Graf to achieve the only [Calendar Year Golden Slam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Slam_(tennis)#Golden_Slam) in tennis history.
>
> 5–7, 6–2, 6–1.
>
> [Final - St. Petersburg Open 2019, Kiki Bertens vs. Donna Vekic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySTzBIE7LRo) - On her 4th championship point, Kiki Bertens was able to strike a backand that clipped the tape, and proved to be too great of a distance for Donna Vekic to run down.
>
> 7-6, 6-4.